# RoR update field - amount limit based on user's role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm thinking about best way to implement logic as follows:

users can update an attribute with amount based on their role.

Example:

`@some_user = User.first.points => 10`

`if current_user.admin?` allow to add up to +100 points for `@some_user`.

`if current_user.cs_staff?` allow to add up to +50 points.

`if current_user.junior_cs_staff?` allow to add up to +10 points.

How would you validate it? Custom model validation or better specify in Pundit policy? (I'm using Pundit).

Answer (score 4):

you can add custom validation method in model, like below

```
validate :validate_user

def validate_user
  if current_user.junior_cs_staff? && points > 10
    errors.add(:points, "You can't add more then 10 points")
  elsif current_user.cs_staff? && points > 50
    errors.add(:points, "You can't add more then 50 points")
  elsif current_user.admin? && points > 100
    errors.add(:points, "You can't add more then 100 points")
  end
end
```

But my suggestion is to show only +10 button when junior_cs_staff is logged in, show only +50 points button cs_staf is logged in and show +100 button when admin is  logged in.

you can add this role conditions in to view

Comment: it will give you syntax error, you forgot to close `if..else` block